# Object doesnt support this property or method: oFldr.GetFolder

Tags: vbscript

I keep getting an error at this function in my code.

```
Function Recurse(oFldr)
    If IsAccessible(oFldr.GetFolder(sSearchRoot)) Then
        For Each oSubFolder In oFldr.SubFolders
            Recurse oSubFolder

            'For Each oFile In oFldr.Files  
            For Each oFile In oFldr.Files

                If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "txt" Then
                    ContentSearchTxt(oFile)
                End If

                If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "doc" Or "docx" Then
                    ContentSearchWord(oFile)
                End If

                If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "xls" Or "xlsx" Then
                    ContentSearchExcel(oFile)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

The error seems to be thrown at my first `if statement`:

```
If IsAccessible(oFldr.GetFolder(sSearchRoot)) Then
```

I am really new to using VBS and was wondering if anyone would be able to push me in the right direction to start?

Comment: As an aside, you can't do this: `If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "xls" Or "xlsx"`. Each `OR` clause must be a complete expression. A better implementation might be to use a `Select Case` statement. Then you can list each extension. For example: `Select Case LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile))` and then list your case statements: `Case "doc", "docx"`, `Case "xls", "xlsx"`, etc. `Case` statements DO let you supply just the value you're trying to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.GetFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1xtf7ta%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a method of the FileSystemObject. So change

```
If IsAccessible(oFldr.GetFolder(sSearchRoot)) Then
```

to

```
If IsAccessible(oFSO.GetFolder(sSearchRoot)) Then
```

where oFSO is defined like

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I do that, I get another error saying `Object required: 'oFldr'`. Do I want to change all instances of `oFldr` to be `oFSO`? I feel like that would not be the case since `oFSO` would not support the `.Files`

Comment: @scapegoat17 - no, just do the one change I mentionend. (Or use the FSO you probably have anyway)

Comment: Would that error above be related to something else then? like not finding Files in that location?

Comment: @scapegoat17 - `Object required: 'oFldr'` means: `oFldr` isn't an object. Given the code you started with, I suspect you changed the name of the parameter to your Function.

Comment: This is what i am doing prior to my function: `Set oFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )` `Set oFldr = oFSO.GetFolder(StartDir)` `Recurse(oFldr)` `Recurse(oFSO.GetFolder(sSearchRoot))`

Comment: @scapegoat17 - does your Function start with `Function Recurse(oFldr)` (as it should)? Do you use `Option Explicit` (as you should)?

Comment: Yes it does start with that.

Comment: @scapegoat17 Please update your question with the modified code and the line where you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the parameter that you are passing to this function.

Before `Function Recurse(oFldr)`

Add

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFldr = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Root_Dir_To_Recurse")
Recurse oFldr
```

Also when the function is called in this way the If statement is not necessary.

The "Next" on your for each oSubFolder is in the wrong place.

Furthermore you have errors in your "Or" statements as well.  Here is a modified version of your function with the If and End If commented out.  The OR statements also have been modified.  You can not simply use OR to specify a different value, you have to make OR another condition, not just another value.

Here is a modified version of your function.  Seeing as this function doesn't have a return value I would also suggest that you change it to a Sub routine as follows:

```
Sub Recurse(oFldr)
    'If IsAccessible(oFldr.GetFolder(sSearchRoot)) Then
        For Each oSubFolder In oFldr.SubFolders
            Recurse oSubFolder
        Next

            'For Each oFile In oFldr.Files  
            For Each oFile In oFldr.Files

                If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "txt" Then
                    ContentSearchTxt(oFile)
                End If

                If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "doc" Or LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "docx" Then
                    ContentSearchWord(oFile)
                End If

                If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "xls" Or LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) ="xlsx" Then
                    ContentSearchExcel(oFile)
                End If
            Next

    'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have done the following to what you have said, but I am still receiving an error saying `Object required: 'oFldr'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now, and tested it out on my own computer and came up with other problems in the code as well.  I have updated my answer with what I have found.